# How to receive email on your IP address with PHP?

Tags: php, email

In php it's easy to send email by **mail()** function, but how to receive email to my home server? Is it possible to host an email service at all?

PS. I'm using mac and running XAMPP stack.

Comment: Are you trying to log into a POP or IMAP account and retrieve email messages with PHP?

Comment: I've heard that IMAP is better and newer than POP3, so I suppose IMAP should be better?

Comment: Could be; I'm just trying to figure out exactly what you're trying to accomplish so that you can improve your answer before it gets closed for being too vague or off-topic.

Comment: Well I want to host an email service on my home iMac. I know how to send email in php, but I want to be able to receive emails as well.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is meant for fast executed applications: You go to a website, PHP fires up a script, executes it, and terminates again. Most of the time, this takes less than a second. In order to receive emails, you'd have to listen on a port continuously. It's something PHP *can* do, but it doesn't mean you should.

What you want is probably just a local mail server, which has nothing to do with PHP. A mail server consists of two parts.

- **A server for sending e-mails**

  Also known as a [Mail Transfer Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent). I'd suggest [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).
- **A server for receiving e-mails**

  Also known as a [Mail Delivery Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent). I'd suggest [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/).

Alternatively, you can use an application that includes both, for instance [Cutedge Systems's MailServe Snow](http://cutedgesystems.com/software/MailServeSnow/).

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to use php to access emails from local server. Since I've no experience in mailing, can you please go into more details about what a  mail server is, and how is it different from HTTP?

Comment: I've heard that IMAP is better and newer than POP3, so I suppose IMAP should be better?

Comment: Yes, IMAP is better. But the mail server you wish to download your emails from has to support it.

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need to setup a mail server, take a look at this [forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=685104) for pointers on how to do it for a mac.

PHP has nothing to do with it.